# @inst_var.method.another_method? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and I came across to this code in Rails application:

```
@datasource = DataSource.find(datasource_id)
@datasource.partnertype.par_description
```

I know that with dot notation in Ruby we access methods. In this case instance method, but what could `par_description` be?

Can method return another method in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method is executed on the value that is returned from the first method

For example consider a string "ABC"

then the the code `"ABC".reverse.reverse` returns "ABC"

here "ABC".reverse returns string "CBA" and reverse method on that string returns "ABC"

Comming to your question @datasource.partnertype may be a function or a associated record and par_description may be another function or a associated colomn for partnertype or a method on the associated record

As you specified that `partnertype` is a table name then

partnertype may be a table that is associated to Datasource table with some association like belongs_to or has_one or any other

So `@datasource.partnertype` returns the associated `partnertype` record for datasource and `@datasource.partnertype.par_description` returns the `par_description` colomn for the associated `partnertype`

For example consider a Tables `User` and `Article` and assume that both of them are associated with a relation `has_one` i.e., User as one Article and Article belongs to a user and Article table has a column named description then the query

```
@user = User.find(1) //1 us ID here
article = @user.article
```

the above query returns the Associated Article record for the user and now if we run `article.description` it returns then it fetches the descrption for that article

insted of Querying multiple times in the database we can use

```
@user.article.description
```

Ruby will then execute a single query and returns the description for us

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in the example above `partnertype` is a table name and `par_description` is name of a column in that table. I don't understand the link.

Comment: @Hairi I have updated my answer with some explanation, Feel free to as doubts if any

Comment: I think I found the link
`belongs_to :partnertype, foreign_key: :dsd_type_id` I thing is the line that bounds them.

Comment: @Hairi updated my answer with a example hope it helps